# Why does readdirSync sort the results automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I retrieve the filenames in the array using the method `fs.readdirSync(path)`. Why are the filenames in the resulting array sorted?

```
function checkFile() {
    try {
        let imgsFolder = './images/';
        let imgs = fs.readdirSync(imgsFolder);

        fs.statSync(imgsFolder);
        return imgs;
    }

    catch (e) {
        console.log("Folder does not exist.");
        fs.mkdirSync("images/");
        console.log("Folder was created.");
    }
}

checkFile();
```

For example the folder has following files: `tts.jpg, array.jpg, man.jpg`, but I retrieve them as `array.jpg, man.jpg, tts.jpg`.

Comment: It is quite possible that the filesystem you are using indexes alphabetically.

Comment: i did a sort by addition in folder, it may not work?

Comment: If you are sorting by addition in folder, then the issue is not in fs.readdirSync(), but rather in your sort code. Can you show us that instead?

Comment: there is no sorting in the code, which is strange

Comment: Node JS does not know what you intend to do with the list, so does not sort it for performance reasons. If it happens to be sorted, it is the filesystem either doing the sorting, or storing them in a way that happens to be sorted.

Comment: ok, thank you, i didn't know this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you read the [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) information that is referenced by the [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) method, following comment comes up

> The order in which filenames are read by successive calls to
>          readdir() depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely
>          that the names will be sorted in any fashion.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be more attentively next time.